# How to implement Brotli for Java

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, compression, haxe

Is there any Brotli Java implementation with example? I found [Brotli Java port](https://github.com/dominikhlbg/BrotliHaxe) and also [Brotli lib on maven](https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.brotli.dec).

```
    byte[] form= Files.readAllBytes(new File("filepath").toPath());
    Brotli brotlic = new Brotli("filepath");
    var compressedbytearray = brotlic.compressArray(form, 1);
    System.out.println(compressedbytearray);
```

After downloading both files, the above code gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class haxe.root.Array ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; haxe.root.Array is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I just want to compress files using Brotli compression in java.

Comment: you'd rather add it as a [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.brotli/dec/0.1.2) in your pom.xml

Comment: @curiosa, I don't have pom.xml

Comment: i've made a working version of the brotli haxe library for many of the targets: https://bitbucket.org/chii/brotlihx/src/master/